# My CSV writer code writes separators between characters and not strings

Tags: python, csv, file-io, output, writer

I have written code which writes to a CSV file, reading from another file. I want to write out particular columns from the input file, so I append them to a list, then separate them by a comma and add them to the row, but the output file shows that the individual words' characters are also separated by commas. I only want words to be separated, not the characters.

```
import csv
def csv_reader(file,path):
    with open(path, 'w') as f1, open(file, 'r') as f2:
        write = csv.writer(f1, delimiter=',')
        read  = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in f2), delimiter="\t")
        i=1
        for row in read:
            if(len(row)==0):
                continue
            if(row[3]=="Trade"):
                continue
            else:
                if(row[6]==""):
                    r = [row[0],row[0],'A',row[8],row[9],row[0]]
                    line = ','.join(r)
                    print(line)
                    write.writerow(line)
                else:
                    r = [row[0],row[0],'B',row[6],row[7],row[0]]
                    line = ','.join(r)
                    print(line)
                    write.writerow(line)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "sales.csv"
    csv_path = "FlowEdge-TRTH-Time_Sales.csv"
    csv_reader(csv_path,path)
```

This shows output like:

```
    0,7,0,0,4,5,0,0,0,0,C,8,.,H,K,",",0,7,0,0,4,5,0,0,0,0,C,8,.,H,K,",",B,",",5,.,7,",",4,",",0,7,0,0,4,5,0,0,0,0,C,8,.,H,K
```

while it should be like:

```
    0700450000C8.HK,0700450000C8.HK,B,5.7,4,0700450000C8.HK
```

when I do the following modification

```
   write.writerow([line])
```

It shows the complete string in one column of excel file meaning there is only one column while I want 6 columns.

Comment: first i suggest to split your code - one method doing everything is bad habbit - and when done that - split read and write in a smaller separate tasks using this advice: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ I believe you will easy find your mistake

Comment: The problem is that you're doing `line=','.join(r)`, which turns the list of columns into a single string with commas, and then passing that string to `writerow`, which will iterate the string, treating each character as its own column. Do one or the other, not both.

Comment: @abarnert but when i pass [line] to row writer then the output file has only one column. And if i directly pass the r list then the output file shows weird texts which remains same even after encoding in unicode

Comment: @abhihacker02 Who told you to pass `[line]`?

Comment: @abarnert okay i thought it myself but when i do as you told i get weird characters which remains same even after encoding in unicode

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by that, but (a) that sounds like an entirely new problem, which means you probably want to ask a new question, and (b) either way, you're going to have to give us a [mcve] rather than making us guess at what your input might be, what you might have gotten wrong in attempting to "encode in unicode", and what those "weird characters" might be.

Comment: You could write all this in about 6 lines flat using pandas: `read_csv`, select desired columns, `to_csv`. Do you really want to create your own csv writer?

Comment: It shows the following weird text -> 䥒ⱃ䥒ⱃⱂ楂⁤牐捩ⱥ楂⁤楓敺Ｌ勾䍉਍㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ⱋ㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ⱋⱂ⸵ⰷⰴ㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ോ《〷㐰〵〰䌰⸸䭈〬〷㐰〵〰䌰⸸䭈䈬㘬㘮ㄬ〬〷㐰〵〰䌰⸸䭈਍㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ⱋ㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ⱋⱂ⸷㌰ㄬ〬〷㐰〵〰䌰⸸䭈਍㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ⱋ㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ⱋⱁ㠱㌬〬〷㐰〵〰䌰⸸䭈਍㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ⱋ㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ⱋⱁ㜱㔬㐰〬〷㐰〵〰䌰⸸䭈਍㜰〰㔴〵〰䌰⸸䭈䄬ㄬ⸵㌱㔬ⰹ㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ോ《〷㐰〵〰䌰⸸䭈〬〷㐰〵〰䌰⸸䭈䈬ㄬ ... I had to delete some of it because it was too long

Comment: @smci But the columns are not always same .It depends on the file being readed so ultimately first i'll have to read it

Comment: @abhihacker02: then you can either articulate the criteria by which a column is kept/dropped, or parameterize the column-list as an argument into your function/executable. It's all very doable. I see you want to select between cols 6:7 and 8:9 on a per-row basis, but that can be done too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
line=','.join(r)
print(line)
write.writerow(line)
```

The `writerow` method wants a list of columns. It will add the commas between the columns (and quote or escape anything that needs it, etc.).

But you're not giving it a list of columns; you're giving it a single string. That's what `','.join(r)` does: turns a list of columns into a single comma-separated string.

When you give `writerow` a string, instead of a list of strings, it treats the string as a sequence of characters. (That's not specific to `csv`; in Python, a string *is* a sequence of characters.) So it treats each character as a column, and adds commas between them.

Just do this:

```
write.writerow(r)
```

Comment: if i directly pass the r list then the output file shows weird texts which remains same even after encoding in unicode

Answer (score 1):

To write rows in a csv file, you should contain each string in brackets.
so if you're using `csvwriter.writerrow()` object if you have a string like 'first_name' you should use brackets around that string to avoid ',' between each character in the csv file.

```
csvwriter.writerow(['first_name'])
```

Also if you want to write more than one rows use nested brackets like below:

```
csvwriter.writerows([['first_name'],['last_name']])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read particular set of columns from one `.csv` file and output them to another file, you might try [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) module.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('to_load.csv', usecols=['col1', 'col2'])
data.to_csv('to_save.csv', index=False)
```

What it does it first loads `csv` to a variable named `data`. Only columns you define in `usecols` get imported. You can reference columns by their names or by index (eg. you can `usecols=[0, 1, 2]` - this will import first 3 columns).

Then the variable can be easily saved to `csv` file again thanks to `.to_csv` method.

Comment: But the columns are not always same .It depends on the file being readed so ultimately first i'll have to read it

Answer (score 0):

The `csv.writerow()` function takes a list of items and writes it to your file with the required delimiters (by default this is a comma). So for example:

The list `['a', 'b', 'c']` is written to the file as `a,b,c`

```
import csv

def csv_reader(file,path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as f_output, open(file, 'r', newline='') as f_input:
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
        csv_input = csv.reader((line.replace('\0', '') for line in f_input))

        for row in csv_input:
            if len(row) and row[3] != "Trade":
                if row[6] == "":
                    output_row = [row[0], row[0], 'A', row[8], row[9], row[0]]
                else:
                    output_row = [row[0], row[0], 'B', row[6], row[7], row[0]]

                print(','.join(output_row))
                csv_output.writerow(output_row)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path="sales.csv"
    csv_path = "FlowEdge-TRTH-Time_Sales.csv"
    csv_reader(csv_path, path)
```

When using csv readers and writers, you should open the file with the `newline=''` argument.

Comment: It shows the following weird text -> 䥒ⱃ䥒ⱃⱂ楂⁤牐捩ⱥ楂⁤楓敺Ｌ勾䍉਍㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ⱋ㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ⱋⱂ⸵ⰷⰴ㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ോ《〷㐰〵〰䌰⸸䭈〬〷㐰〵〰䌰⸸䭈䈬㘬㘮ㄬ〬〷㐰〵〰䌰⸸䭈਍㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ⱋ㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ⱋⱂ⸷㌰ㄬ〬〷㐰〵〰䌰⸸䭈਍㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ⱋ㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ⱋⱁ㠱㌬〬〷㐰〵〰䌰⸸䭈਍㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ⱋ㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ⱋⱁ㜱㔬㐰〬〷㐰〵〰䌰⸸䭈਍㜰〰㔴〵〰䌰⸸䭈䄬ㄬ⸵㌱㔬ⰹ㜰〰㔴〰〰㡃䠮ോ《〷㐰〵〰䌰⸸䭈〬〷㐰〵〰䌰⸸䭈䈬ㄬ ... I had to delete some of it because it was too long.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include some suitable sample lines from your CSV file?  Or you could post a link to the whole file using something like pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all but i found the error in my code

```
    read  = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in f2), delimiter="\t")
```

This was the error as i was using tab as the delimiter in a csv file.

Corrected to

```
    read  = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in f2), delimiter=",")
```